# How to set different style & width of the column in frozen & unfrozen columns table in primeng

Tags: css, angular, primeng, primeng-table

I am currently using PrimeNG table control with a frozen column feature.

Everything working fine and I am able to get frozen column but now I want to modify my frozen and unfrozen column styles and custom width of column for that I have used below property.

**Code:**

```
<p-table [columns]="scrollableCols" [frozenColumns]="frozenCols" [value]="cars" [scrollable]="true" scrollHeight="300px" frozenWidth="250px">
  <ng-template pTemplate="colgroup" let-columns>
    <colgroup>
      <col style="width:200px"> 
      <col style="width:50px">
      <col style="width:100px">
      <col style="width:100px"> 
      <col style="width:100px">
      <col style="width:100px">
    </colgroup>
  </ng-template>
  <ng-template pTemplate="header" let-columns>
    <tr>
      <th *ngFor="let col of columns">
        {{col.header}}
      </th>
    </tr>
  </ng-template>
  <ng-template pTemplate="body" let-rowData let-columns="columns">
    <tr>
      <td *ngFor="let col of columns">
        {{rowData[col.field]}}
      </td>
    </tr>
  </ng-template>
</p-table>
```

**Output :**
[image]

by using width I am able to achieve width of my columns but for the first 2 columns, both froze & unfroze column table automatically taking the same width for all 2 columns I want to assign the different sizes of columns in both froze & unfroze column s.

is it possible to add different sizes for froze & unfroze columns?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All you need is `pTemplate="frozencolgroup"`

```
<ng-template pTemplate="frozencolgroup" let-columns>
        <colgroup>
            <col style="width:200px">
            <col style="width:50px">
        </colgroup>
    </ng-template>
    <ng-template pTemplate="colgroup" let-columns>
        <colgroup>
            <col style="width:100px">
            <col style="width:100px">
            <col style="width:100px">
            <col style="width:100px">
        </colgroup>
    </ng-template>
```

Demo [here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-jopxq4)

**UPDATE:** With scroll table can be broke row height. Below tip function to fix this

```
makeRowsSameHeight() {
    setTimeout(() => {
      if ($('.ui-table-scrollable-wrapper').length) {
        let wrapper = $('.ui-table-scrollable-wrapper');
        wrapper.each(function () {
          let w = $(this);
          let frozen_rows: any = w.find('.ui-table-frozen-view tr');
          let unfrozen_rows = w.find('.ui-table-unfrozen-view tr');
          for (let i = 0; i < frozen_rows.length; i++) {
            if (frozen_rows.eq(i).height() > unfrozen_rows.eq(i).height()) {
              unfrozen_rows.eq(i).height(frozen_rows.eq(i).height());
            } else if (frozen_rows.eq(i).height() < unfrozen_rows.eq(i).height()) {
              frozen_rows.eq(i).height(unfrozen_rows.eq(i).height());
            }
          }
        });
      }
    });
  }
```

UPDATE DEMO: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-primeng-table-frozen-columns-dpsm8l

Comment: its working but some with more data in row its breaking row height and and whole UI messed check this link https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-primeng-table-frozen-columns-4ht7sm

Comment: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-primeng-table-frozen-columns-4ht7sm check this link.

Comment: Great Perfect. Thanks for quick reply.

Comment: One more query as I have almost 100K to 10M rows in my table so is your logic will impact performance lagging ?

Comment: With large dataset I think you should paging

Comment: I have already implemented Paging so on every next page I need to call this function right to calculate new height of row ?

Comment: Yes, every next page

Comment: I am facing one more issue in primeng table can you please help me on this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54211196/first-column-repeating-in-both-froze-unfroze-table-in-primeng-table

Comment: See my answer :)

Comment: @phucnh :- I am also facing the same problem..... from where I need to call function  **makeRowsSameHeight()** ?

Comment: after init data, see my demo with stackblitz