# First column repeating in both froze & unfroze table in Primeng table

Tags: angular, primeng, primeng-table

I am working on one project where I used `PrimeNg` table with froze & unfroze column property and its working fine in normal column creating with `*NgFor` but if I add new column without `*NgFor` its repeating in both froze & unfroze table.

How to overcome this issue as I want that column only on froze column not on unfroze column.

**My Code:**

```
<ng-template pTemplate="header" let-columns>
    <tr>
      <th>All</th>
      <th *ngFor="let col of columns">
        {{col.header}}
      </th>
    </tr>
  </ng-template>
  <ng-template pTemplate="body" let-rowData let-columns="columns">
    <tr>
      <td>
                <p-tableCheckbox
                  [value]="rowData"
                  [attr.disabled]="
                    rowData.setupType === 'No Action' &&
                    rowData.currentStatus === 'INACTIVE'
                      ? 'disabled'
                      : null
                  "
                ></p-tableCheckbox>
              </td>
      <td *ngFor="let col of columns">
        {{rowData[col.field]}}
      </td>
    </tr>
  </ng-template>
```

**Column repeat Issue:**

[image]

How to overcome this issue ?

Guide me if its possible in `PrimeNg` table.

Comment: rowData check what array you getting

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to use template `frozenheader`

```
<ng-template pTemplate="frozenheader" let-columns>
        <tr>
            <th>All</th>
            <th *ngFor="let col of columns">
                {{col.header}}
            </th>
        </tr>
    </ng-template>
```

and `frozenbody`

```
<ng-template pTemplate="frozenbody" let-rowData let-columns="columns">
        <tr>
            <td style="text-align: center">
                <p-tableCheckbox [value]="rowData" [attr.disabled]="
                    rowData.setupType === 'No Action' &&
                    rowData.currentStatus === 'INACTIVE'
                      ? 'disabled'
                      : null
                  "></p-tableCheckbox>
            </td>
            <td *ngFor="let col of columns">
                {{ rowData[col.field] }}
            </td>
        </tr>
    </ng-template>
```

Demo [here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-primeng-table-frozen-columns-dpsm8l)

Comment: Perfect answer its working as expected. Thanks @phucnh